# Why pandas.melt() not working on my dataframe?

Tags: pandas, pandas-melt

I also visited official docs but same syntax is given.
Here's my code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
               'points': [88, 91, 99, 94],
               'assists': [12, 17, 24, 28],
               'rebounds': [22, 28, 30, 31]})
pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['team'], value_vars = ['points','assists'])
df
```

Comment: What are your expected results? Did you know you didn't reset your dataframe to the melt results because you did not `df = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['team'], value_vars = ['points','assists'])`

Comment: Not sure what you want but maybe you just have to catch the return value: `df = pd.melt(df, ....)`. Pandas don't manipulate the original input data frame.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.